# IE10 WWW-authenticate not prompting credentials

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, cross-browser, credentials

I've got a web application which when the first request is made will return a 401 with a response header containing 'WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="test". This prompts a login pop-up in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. However in IE10 and IE11 the credentials aren't requested and other requests are done. Any ideas as to why the login prompt isn't shown would be useful. Thanks